# Wix - How to bundle a configuration file in burn

Tags: sql-server, wix, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2019 express edition from network in my wix installer from the following link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

But it looks like this SQL express installer only accept configuration in a CMD parameter (/ConfigurationFIle="filePath"), so my question is how I can bundle my sql express configuration file so that it can be used when installing SQL express

```
<ExePackage
    InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /Q /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /ConfigurationFile=&quot;MyConfigFile.ini&quot;"
    Name="redist\setup.exe"
    DownloadUrl="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866658"
    .../>
</ExePackage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a way to bundle the configuration file so that my exePackage can use it:

```
<ExePackage
    InstallCommand="/ACTION=Install /Q /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /ConfigurationFile=&quot;[WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder]MyConfigFile.ini&quot;"
    Name="redist\setup.exe"
    DownloadUrl="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866658"
    .../>
    <Payload Id="ConfigurationFileSqlExpress"
        Compressed="yes"
        SourceFile="$(env.PREREQUISITE_FOLDER)\redist\ConfigurationFileSqlExpress.ini"
        Name="ConfigurationFileSqlExpress.ini" />
</ExePackage>
```

It turns out all I need to do is adding a Payload element inside ExePackage and provide the detail (SourceFile, Name) of the config file I'd like to use. Be sure to include the extension .ini in the Name of the Payload (SQL installer expects a .ini file for configration)

Then add the following into InstallCommand so that the config file path can be passed to SQL installer:

```
/ConfigurationFile=&quot;[WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder]ConfigurationFileSqlExpress.ini&quot;
```

[WixBundleExecutePackageCacheFolder]: (built-in variable), gets the absolute path to the currently executing package's cache folder. This variable is only available while the package is executing.

Reference:

Idea: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/SqlExpress-Exepackage-InstallCommand-ConfigurationFile-tp7593994p7601003.html

SQL Serve configuration file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file?view=sql-server-ver15